# IntelliJ IDEA / RubyMine - Run multiple rake tasks at once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, intellij-idea, rake

In a terminal, I can run multiple rake tasks one after another in a single line:

```
rake grunt war app_server:start
```

I can't seem to get this to work in IntelliJ IDEA when trying to create a Configuration to do it. I'm able to fill in the "Task Name" field as above, but when I run the configuration, I get the following error:

```
Don't know how to build task 'grunt war app_server:start' (see --tasks)
```

Does anyone know if I'm just doing something wrong, or is this just not possible in IDEA? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Compounds don't work since they are run in parallel and not in the same process. This makes it impossible to execute for example `environment` task followed by another task such as `elasticsearch:import:all`.

The only way I could get it to work was to create a project-level task, for example `lib/tasks/es.rake`:

```
require 'elasticsearch/rails/tasks/import'

namespace :es do
  task reindex: %w[environment elasticsearch:import:all]
end
```

You then execute `es:reindex` as a top-level task which will execute its dependencies in order.

Answer (score 2):

As an option, in the Idea you can create multiple tasks and combine them in a group:

`Run` -> `Edit Configurations` -> `Add` -> `Compound`